# Assembly: how can i make computer to accept ctrl+(alphabet) as just a capital alphabet?

Tags: assembly, x86

To make my computer to accept ctrl+alphabet key as just a capital alphabet, I think I should make an Int handler for Int09h. But how??
Any answers would be helpful.

Comment: So you want to intercept key-presses and make it look like the user pressed shift+a instead of ctrl+a?  Also, you know doing it with 16bit DOS is only going to work inside your DOS emulator, right?  I tagged this with x86.  Please add more tags and clarification as appropriate (e.g. `[ms-dos]`)

Comment: More context is needed. What platform are you programming for? Can you give a more detailed description of your problem?

Comment: Just convert the keypress value for yourself, after getting it with a non-echo function. So if `01h` is returned (Ctrl-A) you can convert that to `41h`. Another possibility if using DOS is check the keyboard status of shift, control etc keys with `int 16h` function `02h`.

Comment: @WeatherVane To elaborate, just or `40h` into the byte you got if it is smaller than `20h`.

Comment: @FUZxxl quite so, but it's necessary to check the keyboard status flags too, to distinguish `Enter` from `Ctrl-M`.

Comment: @WeatherVane If OP wants to recognize control characters that did not come from Ctrl + ..., then it's going to be slightly more complicated.

Comment: Handling it at the IRQ 1 level can't work. Pressing CTRL-A from the hw point of view is *CTRL-down CTRL-down CTRL-down ... CTRL-down A-down A-down A-down ...*. Unless you want to replace CTRL with SHIFT entirely (which can easily done with `INT 15/AH=4Fh`), you need a more high level hook, one that change the way the OS capitalizes.